# Linq list of interface, interface has member an array of strings, I want linq statement that aggregates all strings from array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, object

I have an array of interfaces in C#, in the interface there is a member, a list of strings, I'm trying to add all the strings together from the array of interface members that has a property of array of strings.

```
IPackingFlowEvaluation[]


public interface IPackingFlowEvaluation
{
    IPackingFlow PackingFlow { get; }

    int Priority { get; }

    bool CanUse { get; }

    string[] Reasons { get; }
}
```

I want a linq statement that will add up all the strings of the array of interface member into one large list of strings. A giant list of reasons containing all the reasons from the array of interfaces that has a member itself that has an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you're after `SelectMany`

```
var reasons = source.SelectMany(e => e.Reasons).ToList();
```

where `source` refers to `IPackingFlowEvaluation[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SelectMany()` for that effect.

```
var allReasons = array.SelectMany(i => i.Reasons.ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: `ToList()` within the `SelectMany` is superfluous.  you're better off without it.